# How to get restrictions of NHibernate ICriteria

Tags: nhibernate

In my system I have separation between place that creates criteria and executes criteria.
I would like to fetch the list of restrictions from specific instance of ICriteria, to perform changes, reuse or construct new criteria instance.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I am sorry but I can't undertand your question. Can you please elaborate or give an example?

Comment: I think O.P. wants to dissect a criteria and modify existing restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criteria API is not designed for this. You can have a look at the underlying CriteriaImpl class but like I said it's not designed for this. You will probably have a much more robust system if you avoid a design that forces you to abuse the NHibernate API. For example by passing arguments to you Criteria creation code that will affect the criteria directly on creation.